# How to create a list of lists from a calculation of the values of other lists

Tags: python

I have three lists of list and one list. I need to make a calculation with those numbers and get one list of lists.

These are my lists:

```
E = [[352,281,230,158], [55,36,57,287], [89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
I = [[0,0,0,0], [11,0,0,0], [640,0,0,35], [0,679,0,0], [0,0,1281,95], [0,5988,0,0]] 
Des = [[18,70,52,72], [55,36,57,287],[89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
DesPro = [25,49,92,250,264,2130]
```

Other data:

```
n = 6 #number of lists within lists
t = 4 #number of elements of those lists within lists`
```

The calculation for each element I need is:

```
S = (E + I - Des) / DesPro
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(n):
  for t in range(T):
    S = (E[i][t] + I[i][t] - Des[i][t]) / DesPro[i]
    print(S)
```

I expected:

```
[[13.36, 8.44, 7.12, 3.44], [0.22448979591836735, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [6.956521739130435, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3804347826086957], [0.0, 2.716, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 4.8522727272727275, 0.35984848484848486], [0.0, 2.8112676056338026, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

But I got:

```
13.36
8.44
7.12
3.44
0.22448979591836735
0.0
0.0
0.0
6.956521739130435
0.0
0.0
0.3804347826086957
0.0
2.716
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
4.8522727272727275
0.35984848484848486
0.0
2.8112676056338026
0.0
0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
E = [[352,281,230,158], [55,36,57,287], [89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
I = [[0,0,0,0], [11,0,0,0], [640,0,0,35], [0,679,0,0], [0,0,1281,95], [0,5988,0,0]] 
Des = [[18,70,52,72], [55,36,57,287],[89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
DesPro = [25,49,92,250,264,2130]
n = 6 #number of lists within lists
T = 4 #number of elements of those lists within lists`
results = []
for i in range(n):
      resultsSubList = []
      for t in range(T):
        S = (E[i][t] + I[i][t] - Des[i][t]) / DesPro[i]
        resultsSubList.append(S)
      results.append(resultsSubList)
print(results)
```

The problem is that you are doing the math, but then you are just logging the variable. In the same way that you have used for loops to deconstruct the input arrays, you need to put it back together.

What you did originally was good, in that it created the correct string of numbers, you just needed to make sure it was storing those numbers in arrays rather than outputting them immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy can do the math for you!

```
import numpy as np

E = np.array()[352,281,230,158], [55,36,57,287], [89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]])
I = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [11,0,0,0], [640,0,0,35], [0,679,0,0], [0,0,1281,95], [0,5988,0,0]]) 
Des = np.array([[18,70,52,72], [55,36,57,287],[89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]]) 
DesPro = np.array([25,49,92,250,264,2130])

(E + I - Des) / DesPro[:,None]
# array([[13.36      ,  8.44      ,  7.12      ,  3.44      ],
#        [ 0.2244898 ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 6.95652174,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.38043478],
#        [ 0.        ,  2.716     ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  4.85227273,  0.35984848],
#        [ 0.        ,  2.81126761,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

---

The `DesPro[:,None]` or alternatively `DesPro[:, np.newaxis]` is necessary to match (broadcast) shapes. [read more on boradcasting (numpy docs)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to organize you data

```
[
    [
        (E[i][t] + I[i][t] - Des[i][t]) / DesPro[i]
        for t in range(T)
    ]
    for i in range(n)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to match up elements from each list and remove the indexing and list comprehensions to do the nested calculation:

```
E = [[352,281,230,158], [55,36,57,287], [89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
I = [[0,0,0,0], [11,0,0,0], [640,0,0,35], [0,679,0,0], [0,0,1281,95], [0,5988,0,0]] 
Des = [[18,70,52,72], [55,36,57,287],[89,65,86,25], [182,236,243,82], [214,221,344,54], [1856,2537,2443,1523]] 
DesPro = [25,49,92,250,264,2130]

S = [[(e + i - des) / despro for e, i, des in zip(elist, ilist, dlist)]
     for elist, ilist, dlist, despro in zip(E, I, Des, DesPro)]

print(S)
```

Output:

```
[[13.36, 8.44, 7.12, 3.44], [0.22448979591836735, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [6.956521739130435, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3804347826086957], [0.0, 2.716, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 4.8522727272727275, 0.35984848484848486], [0.0, 2.8112676056338026, 0.0, 0.0]]
```